# Making GHC post FTP feel pre-FTP

Tags: haskell, ghc

For teaching Haskell to beginners using the recent version of GHC, the types of some functions can be confusing due to the Foldable-Traversable-in-Prelude (FTP).  For example, basic functions on lists such as `length`, `sum` and `product` have types that include the `Foldable` constraint `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`. Similarly for some introductory higher order functions e.g. `foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`.

What is a lightweight way of temporarily enabling pre-FTP behaviour?  Then beginners can still enjoy all the benefits of a recent GHC, and don't have to resort to trying to install older versions, or using Hugs (e.g. as suggested for edX's FP101x 2015 edition).

Comment: Why not just use GHC 7.8? Using hugs I wouldn't recommend

Comment: I agree that I would not recommend Hugs.  But, since using GHC 7.10 and later also has fairly easy workarounds, neither would I recommend GHC 7.8.

Comment: I guess I should have asked: what makes you want 7.10 for teaching? They're both great compilers, supported by stackage lts, equally easy to install, etc. Actually aren't there some issues with latest 7.10 on macs?

Comment: Disclaimer: I only teach on an ad-hoc basis, so this is not a professional instructor speaking.
I prefer using current tools, and the people I "teach"/help seem to also prefer current tools.  They are less buggy, better supported, and as the learner gains mastery, they can smoothly transition into using the tool for real work.

Specifically for GHC, since I use 7.10, I can help others when it comes to finer points, like getting and IDE working, or working with interesting libraries when the learner wants to explore something that's captured their interest.

Comment: @jberryman: works fine on my 10.9.5. also one can't forever remain on 7.8, even if it's for teaching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That could work fine, but we decided to go with something less tedious for http://haskellbook.com/, what we did was we explained what changed and show them how you could assert the list-based type.

```
Prelude> :t length
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
Prelude> :t length :: [a] -> Int
length :: [a] -> Int
```

Between that and the types asserted in the examples & exercises, this has sufficed and if they accidentally encounter a type with Foldable in it, it doesn't cause trouble because we've told them how things changed.

Making them import stuff and not bothering to tell them what happened seems brittle, as they'll get confused if they get off the happy path.

Answer (score 7):

One option demonstrated as follows:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> import Prelude hiding (length, sum, product, foldr, foldl, and, or, any, all)
Prelude> import GHC.OldList
Prelude GHC.OldList>
```

Then you get the old types for everything that was hidden, e.g.

```
length :: [a] -> Int
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
product :: Num a => [a] -> a
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

Comment: or better yet: define your own comppat. module based on bitemyapp's answer, and let them see and understand its contents.